# reading image file with unknown image data *.ITW

Tags: bufferedimage, java-2d, jai, raster

I just want to read and load image data into Java 2D class 
Any hint will be great.
This has been cross posted at java2D forum ( oracle forum)

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2434586&stqc=true

Comment: Just looked at javax.io.ImageIO-->read(File file) it tries to find image reader for a given service provider which does not exist so the method read(File file) returns a null object

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this format is not supported in Java. You can write your own ImageIO plugin, but it is not easy. Here is the official guide:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/extending.fm1.html